# Variable in single instance class is not changing

Tags: typescript, singleton, global

I understand questions with titles like this normally get downvoted but I couldn't think of how to word it well.

I have a class that needs to only have one instance across the whole app. I've learnt that this (I think) is called a singleton but I don't have it set up this way. The way I have it is:

```
import _Storage from '../components/storage/Storage'

export const Storage = new _Storage();
```

and then I can import `Storage` in any file and they will all use the same instance.
The `_Storage` class looks like this:

```
class _Storage {
    isReady: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.isReady = false;
    }

    initialise() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onReady);
    }

    onReady() {
        this.isReady = true;
        File.checkDir(File.dataDirectory, "data").catch(
            () => {
                File.createDir(File.dataDirectory, "data", true);
            }
        );
        File.listDir(File.dataDirectory, "data").then(
            (succ) => {
                if (succ.length === 0) {
                    File.createFile(File.dataDirectory+"data", "data.txt", false);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    async write(data, key?) {
        if (!this.isReady) return;

        let r = await this.read();
        let d = isEqual(r, {}) ? r : JSON.parse(r)

        if (isEqual(d, {})) {
            d["info"] = data;
        }
        else {
            d.info[key ? key : d[0]] = data;
        }

        await File.writeExistingFile(File.dataDirectory+"data", "data.txt", JSON.stringify(d));
    }

    async read(key?) {
        if (!this.isReady) return;

        let d = JSON.parse(await File.readAsText(File.dataDirectory+"data", "data.txt"));
        if (key) {
            return d.info[key];
        }
        return d;
    }

}
export default _Storage;
```

In my App.tsx file I call `Storage.initialise` which, once ready, calls `onReady`. This should update the `isReady` variable to true and with some console.log's, it does. However, if I later call `read` or `write`, it will just return at the first line since `isReady` is back to the default value of false. Surely if there is only one instance of the class and `isReady` is changed, no matter when and where I call a function `isReady` should still be what it was previously set to (that would be `true`). I double checked it was only a single class by printing something from the constructor and sure enough, it is only instantiated once so how come `isReady` doesn't stay true?

I did also try setting it up like a singleton:

```
import _Storage from '../components/storage/Storage'

var StorageSingleton = (function () {
    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var inst = new _Storage();
        return inst;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();
export const Storage = StorageSingleton;
```

but the issue still occurs. What am I missing here?

EDIT: Here's an example which hopefully highlights then problem more:

File 1

```
///File 1
class Foo {
    baz: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.baz = false;
    }

    setBaz() {
        this.baz = true;
    }

    getBaz() {
        return this.baz
    }
}
export default Foo;
```

File 2

```
///File 2
import Foo from "./File1"

export const Bar = new Foo();
```

File 3

```
///File 3
import { Bar } from './File2'

//console.log(Bar.baz) :> false
Bar.setBaz()
//console.log(Bar.baz) :> true
```

File 4

```
///File 4
import { Bar } from './File2'

//console.log(Bar.baz) :> false
console.log(Bar.getBaz()) //:> false

//File 4 and File 3 have the same instance of 'Bar' so why is 'baz' now false if it was set to true in file 3?
```

Comment: Hmm, how are you creating this class? Are you creating multiple times but would like to have the same instance?

Comment: I am only creating 1 instance of this class and am using that single instance everywhere in the app. The first code block in my post is how I have it set up now. I just import `Storage` in all files needed. Those files now have access to the single instance of `_Storage`

Comment: @GytisTG I've added some example code to my post to help explain the issue

Comment: Hmm, but I see var being set as true in my test project (https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-84puyt). Did I still miss something? :|

Comment: That's interesting. Although I can't really test it I do haver another class which I only have 1 instance of and I *think* it works which makes this more confusing. I'll try a blank project but I was provided a different approach below so I'll probably use that.

Comment: Ok, good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a class here.

Consider using a module instead.

You will export functions in your module:

```
let ready = false;

export function initialise() {
    // ...
}

export onReady() {
    // ...
}

export async write(data, key?) {
    // ...
}

export async read(key?) {
    // ...
}
```

In this example ready will not be accessible, you can export it if you want to access it.

Then you can import your module this way:

```
import * as Storage from "path_to_storage";
```

And call function this way:

```
Storage.write(/* params */);
Storage.read(/* params */);
// etc
```

Or you can import some specific function (this give you flexibility):

```
import { initialise as initialiseStorage, read as readStorage } from "path_to_storage";
```

Then use them:

```
initialiseStorage();
readStorage();
```

Comment: I assume that if ready was set to true in File A then in File B, ready would still be true right?

Comment: Yes but that would also be the case with a singleton.

Comment: Ah ok - I'll try it out now. Is there any advantages/disadvantages to using classes/modules?

Comment: In this case, my advice to use module is related to the singleton. Classes are useful when you allow several instances to be built and if they have private states.

Comment: Good to know! I've been testing it although I've run out of time now. It seems to be working although I think I'm trying to call read before it has finished initialising (well I hope that's the issue)

Comment: Can confirm it works! Had to add a little wait function that would stop execution of a function until `isReady` was set to true and that fixed it. Thank you!